# Tensorflow: getting double the expected list of global variables after variable initialization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a neural network as follows:

```
xt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
tht = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
th_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


rlu_1t = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=tf.reshape([xt,x_t,tht,th_t],[1,4]),num_outputs=10)

# 4 state features: x, x_, th, th_
rlu_1t.weights_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[4],minval=-1,maxval=1) # is this 4 or 10?
rlu_1t.biases_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[1],minval=-1,maxval=1)
rlu_2t = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=rlu_1t,num_outputs=10) # hope that makes a copy
rlu_2t.weights_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[10],minval=-1,maxval=1)
rlu_2t.biases_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[1],minval=-1,maxval=1)
Qvalst = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=rlu_2t,num_outputs=2)
Qvalst.weights_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[10],minval=-1,maxval=1)
Qvalst.biases_initializer = tf.random_uniform(shape=[1],minval=-1,maxval=1)
Qvalst.activation_fn = tf.identity
```

When I don't initialize the weights and biases in the neural network, then calling print(tf.global_variables()) outputs:

```
[<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(4, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_1/weights:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_1/biases:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_2/weights:0' shape=(10, 2) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_2/biases:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

When I do initialize the weights and biases in the neural network as follows:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
```

Then calling print(tf.global_variables()) returns double the list of variables I had before (which I don't need):

```
[<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(4, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_1/weights:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_1/biases:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_2/weights:0' shape=(10, 2) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_2/biases:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_3/weights:0' shape=(4, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_3/biases:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_4/weights:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_4/biases:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_5/weights:0' shape=(10, 2) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'fully_connected_5/biases:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - turns out I needed to add tf.reset_default_graph() before the neural network in order to clear the variable list.